# SonarQube integration with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am trying to integrate SonarQube runner in my build process. My build steps consists of an ant build and sonar-runner task. I have attached the Screenshots later. I am getting an error stating "

> Unable to determine database dialect to use within sonar with dialect
>   null jdbc url localhost
>       Build step 'Invoke Standalone SonarQube Analysis' marked build as failure

"-

```
[MyProject] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/Default-SonarQube-Runner/bin/sonar-runner -X -e -Dsonar.jdbc.url=localhost ******** ******** -Dsonar.host.url=http://qa.MyProject.com:9000 ******** ******** -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyProject -Dproject.settings=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyProject/sonar-project.properties
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.7.0_95 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
Linux 3.13.0-48-generic amd64
INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on.
INFO: Runner configuration file: /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/Default-SonarQube-Runner/conf/sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyProject/sonar-project.properties
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyProject/.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.1
07:06:34.641 INFO  - Load global repositories
07:06:34.651 DEBUG - Download: http://qa.MyProject.com:9000/batch/global (no proxy)
07:06:34.744 INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=105ms
07:06:34.745 INFO  - Server id: 20160304110723
07:06:34.747 INFO  - User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
07:06:34.755 INFO  - Install plugins
07:06:34.755 DEBUG - Download index of plugins
07:06:34.755 DEBUG - Download: http://qa.MyProject.com:9000/deploy/plugins/index.txt (no proxy)
07:06:34.841 DEBUG - Loaded 2196 properties from l10n bundles
07:06:34.842 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
07:06:34.842 DEBUG - Download index of jdbc-driver
07:06:34.842 DEBUG - Download: http://qa.MyProject.com:9000/deploy/jdbc-driver.txt (no proxy)
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 0.681s
Final Memory: 3M/59M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: Unable to determine database dialect to use within sonar with dialect null jdbc url localhost
Build step 'Invoke Standalone SonarQube Analysis' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Inside my Jenkins->Manage Jenkins->Configure System , I have configured the sonar qube section as shown in the screenshot below-
[image: SonarQube SetUp]

Here is the screenshot of my build config-

[image]

I am not getting the clue on how to debug ? Any suggestion ?

Here are the version details-

SonarQube Runner 2.4

Sonar Version 5.1

Comment: What version of the SonarQube platform?

Comment: SonarQube Runner 2.4
Sonar Version 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you double check if you are specifying the correct JDBC URL. In the screenshot attached, SonarQube is configured with datasource URL as 'localhost'.

The stacktrace again says you do not have a database dialect specified. This can be specified in the sonar properties file.

Answer (score 0):

I realised, what was wrong here. I had added incorrect database dialect in my jenkins configuration (Jenkins->Manage Jenkins->Configure System). See the screenshot. Earlier i had used

```
localhost
```

instead of

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
```

[image]